# For a given dictionary key, get all the subordinates as a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Given the following data structure

```py
T = {'a': ['b','c'], 'c': ['d', 'r'], 's': ['k']}
```

I need all elements of a given key.

Example:

```py
print(get_hierarchy(T, 'a'))
```

Output:

```
['b','c','d','r']
```

How can I get the final output?

Comment: And you did code exactly what to get there? [mre]? what is the problem with the solution you cooked up?

Comment: I was unable to make that recursive. However, this is small part of my data pipeline.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What's does `get_hierarchy(T, 'a')` do exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want a recursive function:

```py
def get_hierarchy(d, val):
    out = d.get(val, [])
    for v in out:
        out.extend(get_hierarchy(d, v))
    return out


T = {"a": ["b", "c"], "c": ["d", "r"], "s": ["k"]}
print(get_hierarchy(T, "a"))
```

Prints:

```
['b', 'c', 'd', 'r']
```

Comment: Yes, i wanted that to be recursive. However, the above code throwing an error, 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: @luizpy That means you're putting the first argument  as type `str` to `get_hierarchy` (the first argument needs to be a type `dict`)

Comment: Yeah, I made a silly mistake there.